# IBM Worklight - How to read barcode

Tags: cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

I know how to get a picture and how to show a picture in IBM Worklight using a Cordova plug-in.

I am now looking for information on how to read a barcode using the device camera across mobile platforms.

Answer (score 3):

Just googled about the barcode scanner and found [this](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/community/blogs/worklight/entry/using_cordova_plugins_in_worklight_native_barcode_scanning_for_ios15?lang=en). It seems to work for iOS and there is some info in the comments to make it work on Worklight 6.0.

Also, there is [this IBM Redbook](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/redpieces/abstracts/sg248117.html?Open). Get the PDF file and look for the section "Creating the shell for the bar code scanner"; there are detailed instructions on how to configure the Barcode Scanner (it covers the Android part)

Comment: @Rincon thank you very much Rincon..i got some idea how to read barcodes ...can u say how to pass my capture image for scaning

Comment: Are you trying to take pictures, store them and then pass them as bar codes? I believe with the samples above (specially the IBM Redbook one), you can make "live" scanning using the phone's camera, no need to store. Have you tried something and it didn't work? If so, could you provide some more code to see what is failing?

Answer (score 1):

Cordova has such plug-ins:
See: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/iOS/BarcodeScanner
or: https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner

Comment: Hey Yaron...Thanks for your immediate reply...Could you please suggest other than this?Because I tried this one...But not able to understand fully...but i don't know how to start read bar codes from auto focus using work light ..???Please help.

Comment: Can you expend on that please? The concept is that you take a picture of the barcode, the plug-in scans this and does whatever you want based on the "contents" of the barcode. Where do you fail?

Comment: @IdanAdar How can i read the bar codes using mobile camera auto focus.i need to write the codes inside the IBM Work light common folder.can u help me..?

Comment: @Kiran, sure, please learn how to use Cordova plug-ins in Worklight. Read through these training modules: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#cordova

Answer (score 0):

Search Phonegap plugin ,such as this: 
https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugins/tree/master/Android/BarcodeScanner